# React Dynamic Components and Create Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Form() {
  const [components, setComponents] = useState(["1"]);

  function addComponent() {
    setComponents([...components, 1]);
    
  }

  const defaultState = [
    {
      title: "",
      desc: "",
    },
  ];

  const [form, setForm] = useState(defaultState);

  const handleChangeTitle = (e) => {
    setForm({
      title: e.target.value,
      desc: form.desc,
    });
  };

  const handleChangeDesc = (e) => {
    setForm({
      title: form.title,
      desc: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <button onClick={addComponent}>+</button>
        {components.map((item, i) => (
          <>
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              <label>
                Title:
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="title"
                  onChange={(e) => handleChangeTitle(e)}
                />
              </label>
              <label>
                Description:
                <input
                  type="text"
                  desc="desc"
                  onChange={(e) => handleChangeDesc(e)}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Hi, I have a code like the one at the top. Pressing the "+" button on the page extracts a text input for title and description on the screen. This means that input numbers are increasing according to the user's request. I want to print these inputs, which have more than one goal, in a single object (defaultState in form state). For example, if you want to use the user pressed the plus button 2 times and the view of the object should be as follows: {title:'Title:'1st title', desc:'1.content', title:'2.title', desc:'2.content', title:'3.title', desc:'3.content'}

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want do. Is there an issue with the code? What are you expecting? Can you provide more context and explain what you want the code to do, more precisely?

Comment: What'd you want to accomplish on clicking the `+` button? Would you want to render more input elements or Collect and add values of input fields into an array?